# how to decode png with tensorflow 2.x API without using the palette contained in the png file

Tags: tensorflow2.0

png files are usually index values assosiated with a default palette. by default, index values can be read by PIL image, for example:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    from PIL import Image
    import numpy as np    
    path = '1.png'
    image1 = Image.open(path)
    print(image1.mode)
    array1 = np.array(image1)
    print(array1.shape)
    print(set(list(array1.reshape(-1))))
```

the results:

```
P
(1024, 543)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
```

index can be converted to palette colors:

```
image2 = image1.convert('RGB')
print(image2.mode)
array2 = np.array(image2)
print(array2.shape)
print(set([tuple(x) for x in list(array2.reshape(-1, 3))]))
```

the results are

```
RGB
(1024, 543, 3)
{(0, 255, 255), (255, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255), (85, 255, 170), (170, 255, 85), (255, 0, 0), (255, 170, 0), (0, 170, 255), (0, 85, 255), (255, 85, 0), (0, 0, 170)}
```

the question is, by default, tensorflow 2.x API read palette colors, is there a way to read the index values?

```
tensor = tf.io.read_file(path)
tensor = tf.image.decode_png(tensor, channels=3)
array3 = tensor.numpy()
print(array3.shape)
print(set([tuple(x) for x in list(array3.reshape(-1, 3))]))

(1024, 543, 3)
{(0, 255, 255), (255, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255), (85, 255, 170), (170, 255, 85), (255, 0, 0), (255, 170, 0), (0, 170, 255), (0, 85, 255), (255, 85, 0), (0, 0, 170)}
```

Answer (score 0):

my temporary solution is to remove all the palette assosiated with png files. Still looking for more efficient solutions

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
img = Image.open('1.png')
img = np.array(img)
img = Image.fromarray(img)
img.save('2.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ideal solution**

A clean solution would be to re-implement a custom op to decode a PNG without palette conversion.

Currently, the palette conversion in TF for the `decode_png`-op is done at [core level](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/38cdb9ff8548efc920039d68dd94b5581db6314a/tensorflow/core/lib/png/png_io.cc#L284):

```cpp
// convert palette to rgb(a) if needs be.
if (context->color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_PALETTE)
  png_set_palette_to_rgb(context->png_ptr);
```

---

**Work-around solution**
(*TF2.X*)

As you've mentioned PIL in your sample code, you could wrap the PIL-call with `tf.py_function` in order to get the desired behavior, like:

```py
def read_png(mask):
    def read_fn(p):
        return np.asarray(Image.open(p.numpy().decode()))
    return tf.py_function(read_fn, [mask], tf.uint8)
```

and then read a *paletted* PNG-image without automatic palette application, like:

```py
img = read_png(path)
img= img.numpy()
print(img.shape)
print(set(list(img.reshape(-1))))
```

Sample output

```
(1024, 543)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
```

---

**Note**: in TF1.X this works only in graph-mode, and you would have to use `tf.py_func` to wrap the TF around PIL-function (+ some minor changes).